# I have a table with more than 100 columns, some of the columns have string value which I want to change to numeric value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table with more than 100 columns. Some of the columns which I don't know have some different string values in it, however its supposed to have integer type. I would like to change those string value to int number 1. The number can be same for all those string values that's fine. So, technically i want to create a loop that can loop through every column finds string value and changes it to 1.

I am not sure how that's done. 
Can someone please assist me :).

My main quest was to find all those columns with those string values, i managed to do it through stack overflow assistance. But, there were lots of columns with string value, so i cannot individually hunt those string value and change it one by one as it can take long time.

df2.select_dtypes(include = ['object'])

The code managed to pull all the columns with string value, but my next step that i am currently experiencing difficulty in is to change those columns string values to a numeric value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'` , then `fillna` in your case you want the fill number as 1 , after that `combine_first`

```
df2=df2.select_dtypes(include = ['object']).apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')\
         .fillna(1).combine_first(df2)
```

---

```
subdf2=df2.select_dtypes(include = ['object'])
for x in list(subdf2):

    df2[x]=pd.to_numeric(df2[x],errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Comment: Just wondering, is there maybe a for loop approach to answering this ?.

Comment: @krijan it can be , but apply is another layout of for loop , so they just almost the same, I will update

Comment: please update me with it :) I really appreciate it. Thank you

Comment: Hello, i am getting some KeyError : 'x', is it possible to know what the issue is ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193667/discussion-between-krijan-and-wenyoben).